# returning SQL results where bit value = 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a database of 3 Tables (see screenshot)

[image]

I need to return the customers where marketing is allowed.

I'm able to return customers title using a where clause but im not sure how to then filter the customers where marketing is allowed. I've looked through the where and join clause but maybe im missing something?

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Title
FROM   Customer AS Cust
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Statuses AS S 
              WHERE S.statusID = Cust.statusID 
              AND S.isMarketingAllowed = 1);
```

Please note: 
While it is possible to get the same results, with similar performance, with a JOIN operation, I see it as less readable. A JOIN operation should be used when you need to **access data** (by the select clause) from the second table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added a comment to the comment below which i may have missed in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would be something like:

```
SELECT c.Forename, c.Surname, c.Email, t.Description, s.IsMarketingAllowed
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Statuses s ON c.StatusID = s.StatusID
INNER JOIN Titles t ON c.Title = t.TitleID
WHERE s.IsMarketingAllowed = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think i may have missed some information in my original question. At the moment i have the following statement : 
`code`  select Forename, Surname, Email from Titles, Customers, Statuses  where Customers.Title =  Titles.TitleID;

This is what i need to ammend to return the customers where marketing is allowed if that makes sense?

Comment: You should use write JOINS explicitly instead of listing your tables with commas. Have you tried running the query above?

Comment: I ran the query you commented, but like I said In my reply, it wasn't what I needed because I Missed some information on what I already have.
Also, what do you mean by explicitly writing JOINS?

Comment: Ok try it now... I put in the columns you wanted. Basically it's not best practice to list tables and use a WHERE clause. It is advisable instead to join them using the JOIN syntax... Then the ON specifies the IDs that should link the tables

Comment: Thanks a lot! how would i incorporate my current query with that one? I need to return titleDescription from the Titles table which i did by doing the following :

`code` select Description Forename, Surname, Email from Titles, Customers  where Customers.Title =  Titles.TitleID; `code`

Comment: Just add another join to bring in that table. Then you can select columns from there. See the update above